# Is Azure Key Vault safer than Azure Storage Blob with Encryption enabled or Cosmos DB with also has encryption enabled by default?

Tags: encryption, azure-cosmosdb, azure-keyvault

I have impression that people think Azure Kay Vault is safer, but I am not sure why, can someone help explain?

Let's consider one scenario where we want to store our customer's sensitive data, like their Azure subscription credential. One solution is to use Azure Cosmos DB which has encryption at rest enabled by default, another solution is to use Azure Key Vault. Is there any particular reason Azure Key Vault is better than Cosmos DB solution?

Thanks.
Lidong

Comment: I would recommend going through KeyVault general documentation and its purpose. It is about access: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault
CosmosDB encryption at rest serves different purpose, securing sensitive data stored in your db: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-encryption-at-rest

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any particular reason Azure Key Vault is better than Cosmos
> DB solution?

First of all, you may be mistaken. These are actually two different levels of service.

Refer to your usage scenario, you should use encrypted storage or cosmos db to store sensitive user data. And azure keyvault should be used to encrypt and save keys and secrets, including storage account keys and data encryption keys.

Azure KeyVault is equivalent to adding another layer of protection to the original protection, and only allowed specific users can access the storage service or cosmos db.You can use encryption technology to encrypt data in transit or data written to Azure storage using SSE. You can keep sensitive storage access keys in the Azure keystore.

Have a look of the azure key vault official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/basic-concepts

Comment: Thanks, both Cosmos DB and Azure Storage manage the encryption keys themselves, so I could simply use Cosmos DB, and don't need Azure Key Vault at all, right? Is it recommended in practice, is there any security concern?